# How to properly use Apache's mod_env module to modify PATH?

Tags: apache, path, cgi

I have a bunch of python scripts that start with this shebang line:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

When attempting to run the scripts at the command line, all works as expected.  When using Apache, I get the "Internal Server Error" message.  Inspecting the error logs, Apache reports:
`env: python3: No such file or directory.`

At first I thought that this could be related to the env command.  However, using a perl script with this shebang line:

`#!/usr/bin/env perl`
works fine!

I believe this may be due to how the PATH is setup in Apache.  When I output Apache's environment using the working perl script, the PATH is reported as `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.  On my machine, both `env` and `perl` are listed in `/usr/bin`, but `python3` is located at `/usr/local/bin`, which is not included in Apache's path as shown above.

I figured I needed to add `/usr/local/bin` to Apache's PATH and have have tried using both `SetEnv` and `PassEnv PATH` as described in Apache's documentation here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html

However, these don't appear to have any affect as the issue persists.

What am I doing wrong?

PS - When I change the shebang line to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` the script runs as expected. However I'd like to preserve the `env` method for portability purposes.

Comment: after your attempt to change the path, if you check apache's path from your perl script as you did before, does it show /usr/local/bin?

Comment: No, it stays the same.  Even after I use SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin directive, the PERL script still outputs the same PATH as I originally indicated.  So its seems neither SetEnv or PassEnv have any effect.

Comment: Then I have no idea! I hope someone else out there can help you....

Answer (score 2):

Update: while I wasn't able to get the `SetEnv` or `PassEnv` directives to work, I managed to get the desired behavior by modifying Apache's `envvars` file with the line:

`export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"`

and then restarting the Apache service.

The location of the `envvars` file probably varies by installation / distribution, but you can find where it is by checking the `apachectl` script, which contains a line where the `envvars` file is referenced.

On my system it was at `/etc/apache2/envvars`.